# Large digit numbers

Tags: c++, c++11, numeric

The program is simple. The user inputs `n` and `n` amount of numbers and i try to add zeros in between adjacent digits. For example if the user enters 9(`n`) digits as 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 (spaced out), the program outputs 10203040506070809. The program works well for up to n=8 digits but i get funny answers from n=9 digits upwards. The range of n should be `3<=n<=15` . My program is as follows:

```
int main()
{
    cout << "\nEnter n and n values: \n";
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<long long>nums;
    int en = n;
    while (en > 0)
    {
        long long x;
        cin >> x;
        nums.push_back(x);
        --en;
    }

    int r = 2 * n - 2;
    long long new_val = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        new_val = new_val + nums[i] * (pow(10, r - j));
        j += 2;
    }

    cout << new_val << endl;
}
```

I don't know how to solve the issue of funny answers from n=9 to n=15.

Comment: Have you tried running under debugger or adding `cout`s to see there are errors in any of the intermediate values.

Comment: If you only have to deal with single digits, consider sticking to characters. eg: `char x; cin >> x; nums.push_back(x); nums.push_back('0');`

Comment: @PaulRooney For n>9, when i put break point at the beginning of the for loop to calculate `new_val` , the second value of `new_val` (after `new_val = 0`) is totally wrong or even negative.

Comment: Well what is the value for `pow(10, r - j)` in that instance? Take apart the calculation  and see if you discover where it diverts from the value you expect.

Comment: By the way, `pow` works in floating point. Sooner or later the results get imprecise and you'll have truncation errors when converting from floating point back to integers.

Comment: You don't need `pow()` at all. Using simple multiplication, the output works fine for me at `n=9`: https://ideone.com/ACVccd. For each loop iteration after the 1st one, simply multiply `new_val` by 100 before adding `nums[i]`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks. I'm trying to modify your code to work for n =11 to n = 15 because it still seems to truncate the values for higher values of n.

Comment: Or is it that `long long` can't hold a 29 digit number?

Comment: @TosinAl: `long long` is 64bits and can hold up to 19 digits. Its max value is `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`. Assuming `n=10` with an input sequence of `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1` than `1020304050607080901` is already 19 digits, so `n>=11` will overflow. For higher values, you would have to use a BigNumber library (compilers don't have 128-bit numeric types yet), or use `std::string` instead of `long long`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks. Sadly, I can't tick your answer as the right answer. I don't understand stackoverflow sometimes.

Comment: @TosinAl that is because I didn't post any answer, only comments

Comment: Does the numerical value of the digits matter? No. So keep it as chars and strings to make your life easier.

Comment: @TosinAl I posted an actual answer now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is `long long` is only 64-bits in size, and thus can only hold up to 19 digits. Its maximum value is `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`.

It is possible to make your code work correctly up to `n=10` if you simply remove `pow()` (which operates on floating-point types, not integer types).  For the 2nd and subsequent loop iterations, you can simply multiply `new_val` by 100 before adding `nums[i]`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "\nEnter n and n values: \n";
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<long long> nums;
    int en = n;
    while (en > 0)
    {
        long long x;
        cin >> x;
        nums.push_back(x);
        --en;
    }

    long long new_val = 0;
    if (n > 0)
    {
        new_val = nums[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
        {
            new_val *= 100;
            new_val += nums[i];
        }
    }

    cout << new_val << endl;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/ACVccd)

However, `1020304050607080901` is 19 digits, so `n>=11` will overflow past the max value of `long long`.

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/P4WA9D)

For such high values, you need to use a BigNumber library (as most compilers do not yet have a native 128-bit numeric type).  Or, just use `std::string` instead of `long long`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "\nEnter n and n values: \n";
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> nums;
    int en = n;
    while (en > 0)
    {
        int x;
        cin >> x;
        nums.push_back(x);
        --en;
    }

    ostringstream new_val;
    if (n > 0)
    {
        new_val << nums[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
            new_val << '0' << nums[i];
    }

    cout << new_val.str() << endl;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/VWSPmJ)

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to suggest a different approach to this problem. Since containers will give you trouble holding those large numbers, then don't with them as numbers, try string instead:

After you get the numbers from the user and store them in the nums vector, do the following:

```
string output = "";
char temp;
for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++){
   temp = nums [i] + '0';
   output += temp;
   if (i != (nums.size()-1))
      output += "0";
}
cout << output;
```

Using this method, the user can enter any number as large as they want. If you want the number to be from 9 to 15, you can simply add validation at the beginning without having to deal with complicated containers.